# Remove jQuery from Checkout pages

Tags: local.xml, jquery

I want to remove jQuery from my checkout pages we arent using it there and the checkout button doesn't work because of conflict.

Shouldn't it be something in `local.xml` like this?

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Its introduced in `local.xml` as this:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name>
</action>
```

Or the names here aren't the same as names and aliases used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to leverage the "removeItem" function like so:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Note this will remove the scrip from the cart page, and not the checkout page.

If you want to remove it from checkout, simply swap out the `<checkout_cart_index>` handle with `<checkout_onepage_index>`